# Single instance of a python daemon (with python-daemon)

Tags: python, linux, init.d, python-daemon

I want to create a program that runs forever, which there is only one instance running at a time and that can be launched with an init.d script. [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) seems to be a good choice to do that as it is the reference implementation of [PEP 3143](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/).

Anyway I can't understand what the PID lock file is for, since it doesn't prevent the program to be run twice.

Should I manually check for the existence of the lock file in my init.d script (based on '/etc/init.d/skeleton') ? Also how am I supposed to kill it ? Get the PID number in the PID file and send a SIGTERM ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What makes you say this: "what the PID lock file is for, since it doesn't prevent the program to be run twice". If the PID file is locked, depending on the lock implementation, it can prevent the program from running twice (the second instance won't get the lock).

Comment: And, yes, use the PID in the PID file to kill the daemon.

Comment: I was looking at processes in htop and I saw two processes after two start. One of them was sleeping it was not the behavior I expected.

Comment: if one was sleeping, it was probably waiting on the lock - effectively, the process was started but not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Sander Marechal's code whose site is currently down so here's the link to a pastebin : http://pastebin.com/FWBUfry5

Below you can find an example of how you can use it, it produce the behavior I expected : it does not allow you to start two instances.

```
    import sys, time
    from daemon import Daemon


    class MyDaemon(Daemon):
            def run(self):
                    while True:
                            time.sleep(1)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
            if len(sys.argv) == 2:
                    if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
                            daemon.start()
                    elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
                            daemon.stop()
                    elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
                            daemon.restart()
                    else:
                            print "Unknown command"
                            sys.exit(2)
                    sys.exit(0)
            else:
                    print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
                    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it effectively prevents via the PID file that a second instance is started.  Are you using it correctly?  My example is based on what I found at [the PEP 3143 reference](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) and in the sources:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import daemon, os, time, lockfile

with daemon.DaemonContext(
    pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('./pydaemon.pid'),
    working_directory=os.getcwd()):
  for i in range(10):
    with open('./daemon.log', 'a') as logFile:
      logFile.write('%s %s\n' % (os.getpid(), i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I start that once, it creates the PID lock file.  If I start it a second time, the second instance sleeps until the first is finished; normal daemons won't finish, so this effectively blocks the second instance for good.  If, however, the first daemon terminates, the second is started.